# Use of multiple DescriptorSets vs more Uniform updates

Tags: c++, vulkan

I've just started learning vulkan and looked through several tutorials/samples and I notices something: everyone uses 1 struct for uniform loading, containing all the relevant data(model, view, projection matrix etc.). These structs are updated every frame ENTIRELY.

Now my question: Is that because the writers were "lazy" and instead of creating seperate unforms for seperate frequencies (e.g. projection, since it only needs to be loaded once) they just used 1 struct because it doesn't require additional setup, or is it because the performance is better when loading 1 "bigger" struct more frequenty than creating multiple sets.

Comment: I can only speak for my examples, and for those I try to keep it simple (as far as that's possible with Vulkan). That's why I only use one descriptor set per UBO. An example demonstrating multiple sets is on my list but not yet finished. But note that for something as static as a projection matrix you could go with push constants instead of dedicated DS.

Comment: @SaschaWillems it were your examples(and those of Alexander Overvoorde) I was refering to. At first sight they are quite monstrous, but if you read through the code, they are quite simple. They were a great help for starting with vulkan, so I want to thank you personally for providing these examples. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most demo/example code is lazy. Typically it's to avoid over-complicating the code with concepts that aren't needed for the result.

Also demos generally have 1 draw call (only rendering one model) so there is no need to change descriptor sets in them.

Also frequency of change is within recording of a single command buffer. So if you have a view matrix which will remain constant for the duration of the frame then you can put it at the start of the layout together with the projection matrix.

Comment: with "start of the layout" you mean the beginning of the renderpass? anyways, thanks

Comment: No I mean with binding number 0 which is then used with (nearly) all draw calls in the command buffer.

Comment: I have one last question: If shaders get bigger with more variables(10-20), would you start creating different buffers, or would you still stick to the simple approach with a single buffer and push constants?

Comment: @Dynamitos if those variables are related (always changed together) then I'd prefer them to be in a single descriptor.